# Making Glyphicon Calendar icon clickable with React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is there a way to make the calendar glyphicon open the datetime picker when clicked? I currently just have the button but it can't be clicked. I’ve been struggling to find something that’s specific to React.

```
<div className={class}>
    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure why this was tagged with c#. Please don't add irrelevant tags to your questions

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bind onClick event on

```
<i onClick={this.showCalendar.bind(this)} className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>`
```

and write logic in showCalendar function of your component to show Calendar component.
For more details on event handling have a look at official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) of react.

Components [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) is used for conditional rendering of component. You should place all variable which can change view in state object of component and call setState method to update state, it will automatically re-render component.

A sample component is given below

```js
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { showCalendar: false };
  this.showCalendar = this.showCalendar.bind(this);
  this.hideCalendar = this.hideCalendar.bind(this);
 }
 
 showCalendar(){
  this.setState({ showCalendar: true });
 }
 
 hideCalendar(){
  this.setState({ showCalendar: false });
 }
 
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <button onClick={this.showCalendar}>Show Calendar</button>
    {this.state.showCalendar &&
     <div style={{border: 'solid 1px gray'}}>
      <h3>Calendar</h3>
      <button onClick={this.hideCalendar}>Hide Calendar</button>
     </div>
    }
   </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

If you are new to React.js read react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), it is very helpful and easy

Comment: Thanks for that. How should the showCalendar function look? I'm a bit confused as to what to write in there to be honest to get this to work.

Comment: That’s really helpful thanks. I’ll let you know how it goes tomorrow!